# matplotlib how to plot multiple lines with defined colours?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I get an error when I plot with colours, and works fine without it. My line colours need to be restricted to 2 defined values.

**This works** in Jupyter Notebook

```
import random
xStart = random.sample(range(1, 10), 6)
xStart.sort()
xEnd = [x + random.randint(1, 6) for x in xStart]
yval = list(range(1, 7))
colours = ['r']*6
colours[1] = 'b'
print(xStart)
print(xEnd)
print(yval)
print(colours)
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax1.plot([xStart,xEnd], [yval,yval], '-', linewidth=1) #, color=colours)
plt.show()
```

[image: Multiple line segments]

**This does not work**.
If I uncomment the color argument, the code throws an (elaborate) error. While I can draw each line segment in a loop and colour each red or blue, I assume it will be slower than the below code. In this toy example I have 6 lines, but in reality I have 12,000 lines and it takes a few minutes, drawing one line at a time in a loop.

I think the error is related to the size of my colour argument; it is likely expecting 1 (at a time internally) whereas I am providing a list of 6.

```
import random
xStart = random.sample(range(1, 10), 6)
xStart.sort()
xEnd = [x + random.randint(1, 6) for x in xStart]
yval = list(range(1, 7))
colours = ['r']*6
colours[1] = 'b'
print(xStart)
print(xEnd)
print(yval)
print(colours)
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax1.plot([xStart,xEnd], [yval,yval], '-', linewidth=1, color=colours)  #--> Only change from above code
plt.show()
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in
>   to_rgba(c, alpha)
>       131     try:
>   --> 132         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
>       133     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
>
> **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in
>   **call**(self, obj)
>       339                 pass
>       340             else:
>   --> 341                 return printer(obj)
>       342             # Finally look for special method names
>       343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in
>   (fig)
>       236 
>       237     if 'png' in formats:
>   --> 238         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
>       239     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
>       240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in
>   print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
>       120 
>       121     bytes_io = BytesIO()
>   --> 122     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
>       123     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
>       124     if fmt == 'svg':
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in
>   print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation,
>   format, **kwargs)    2214                     orientation=orientation,
>   2215                     dryrun=True,
>   -> 2216                     **kwargs)    2217                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer    2218                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in
>   print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
>       505 
>       506     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
>   --> 507         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
>       508         renderer = self.get_renderer()
>       509         original_dpi = renderer.dpi
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in
>   draw(self)
>       428             # if toolbar:
>       429             #     toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
>   --> 430             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>       431         finally:
>       432             # if toolbar:
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in
>   draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        53                 renderer.start_filter()
>        54 
>   ---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        56         finally:
>        57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self,
>   renderer)    1297     1298
>   mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
>   -> 1299                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)    1300     1301
>   renderer.close_group('figure')
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in
>   _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
>       136     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       137         for a in artists:
>   --> 138             a.draw(renderer)
>       139     else:
>       140         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in
>   draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        53                 renderer.start_filter()
>        54 
>   ---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        56         finally:
>        57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py in draw(self,
>   renderer, inframe)    2435             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
>   2436 
>   -> 2437         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)    2438     2439         renderer.close_group('axes')
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in
>   _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
>       136     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       137         for a in artists:
>   --> 138             a.draw(renderer)
>       139     else:
>       140         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in
>   draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        53                 renderer.start_filter()
>        54 
>   ---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        56         finally:
>        57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in draw(self,
>   renderer)
>       765                 self._set_gc_clip(gc)
>       766 
>   --> 767                 ln_color_rgba = self._get_rgba_ln_color()
>       768                 gc.set_foreground(ln_color_rgba, isRGBA=True)
>       769                 gc.set_alpha(ln_color_rgba[3])
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in
>   _get_rgba_ln_color(self, alt)    1267     1268     def _get_rgba_ln_color(self, alt=False):
>   -> 1269         return mcolors.to_rgba(self._color, self._alpha)    1270     1271     # some aliases....
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba(c,
>   alpha)
>       132         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
>       133     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
>   --> 134         rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
>       135         try:
>       136             _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha] = rgba
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in
>   _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
>       183         # float)`and`np.array(...).astype(float)` all convert "0.5" to 0.5.
>       184         # Test dimensionality to reject single floats.
>   --> 185         raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
>       186     # Return a tuple to prevent the cached value from being modified.
>       187     c = tuple(c.astype(float))
>
> **ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: ['r', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']**

Comment: You will get answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851913/python-plotting-colors-labels-for-an-unknown-number-of-lines-without-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-colored-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure/4805456)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get different colored lines for different plots in a single figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-colored-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure)

Comment: I do not believe it is a duplicate of <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-colored-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure">How to get different colored lines for different plots in a single figure?</a> since I read through that earlier and it did not help. Here I am drawing multiple lines with one ax.plot() command and that is why the colour argument is not working.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35971096/4932316) answer on the link you shared. You can first plot the lines using your axis handle ax and then later change the line colors using predefined colors

Comment: Bazingaa, You are a genius! Thanks that worked like a champion :) Is there a way I can upvote your answer also? I have upvoted the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

OK thanks to Bazingaa and this thread, [How to get different colored lines for different plots in a single figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-colored-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure/35971096#35971096)

...the final code is as follows.

Since I am drawing multiple lines with one ax.plot() command, the colour argument will not take. IMHO it should since it logically makes sense and should be an enhancement matplotlib does. Nonetheless, here is the solution as Bazingaa pointed out to me.

For those interested, as expected this code does run a LOT faster compared with drawing 12K lines in a loop (in order to draw & color them one at a time with individual ax.plot() commands).

```
import random
xStart = random.sample(range(1, 10), 6)
xStart.sort()
xEnd = [x + random.randint(1, 6) for x in xStart]
yval = list(range(1, 7))
colours = ['r']*6
colours[1] = 'b'
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax1.plot([xStart,xEnd], [yval,yval], '-', linewidth=1) #, color=colours)  #Leaving the color argument commented
#Add new code to colour after the fact
for idx,line in enumerate(ax1.lines):
        line.set_color(colours[idx])
plt.show()
```