# How to assign these 20 random colors to 20 random x, y pairs in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, colors

This creates x and y of length 20 and 20 RGB triplets. I'd like to assign each color to one point and have started from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53961980/3904031) and answers to the very old question [How to get different colored lines for different plots in a single figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4805048/3904031).

But instead of twenty random dots of random colors I get this weird output, which makes me think that I don't understand anything anymore.

**Question:** How can I assign these 20 random colors to the 20 random x, y pairs?

[image: crazy plot]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ran = np.random.random((5, 20))
x, y = ran[:2]
colors = ran[2:].T
print('colors.shape', colors.shape)
colors = [list(thing) for thing in colors] # removing this line doesn't affect the result

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'o', colors)   # ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color=colors) throws exception
plt.show()
```

**Note:** If instead I try `ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color=colors)` I get errors:

```
File "/path/to/matplotlib/colors.py", line 177, in to_rgba
rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
File "/path/to/matplotlib/colors.py", line 240, in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle
raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why that plot looks the way it does, but what the OP *meant to try* is now shown as the "wrong way" below.

The solution is to stop trying to assign a different color to each marker on a single line, but instead to make a scatter plot which is what this really is!

[image: wrong way] [image: right way]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ran = np.random.random((6, 20))
x, y, s = ran[:3]
colors = ran[3:].T
print('colors.shape', colors.shape)
colors = [list(thing) for thing in colors]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'o') 
for line, color in zip(ax.lines, colors):
        line.set_color(color)
ax.set_title('WRONG Way', fontsize=14)
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, color=colors) 
ax.set_title('RIGHT Way', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```